# Facebook Account kit Integration get facebook profile picture in android

Tags: android, facebook-account-kit

I try to integrate Facebook using Facebook account kit,login successful but I also want to get Facebook account profile picture,name and Email.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook Login and Account Kit are separate products. When somebody logs in with Account Kit all that you get as a developer is their phone number or email. If you'd like Facebook profile pictures, names, etc you should use Facebook Login.